# mysql EAV model - how to select multiple attributes stacked

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have table with two columns:

> product_id and attr_value_id

With this query I get 39 rows:

> SELECT * 
>   FROM ka_product_attributes
>   WHERE attr_value_id
>   IN ( 655, 656, 658 )

and with this query I get 58 rows:

> SELECT * 
>   FROM ka_product_attributes
>   WHERE attr_value_id
>   IN ( 655, 656, 658, 589 )

how to select all product_id's that have attr_value_id 589 and one of the following attr_value_id 655, 656, 658?

Something like this:

> SELECT * 
>       FROM ka_product_attributes
>       WHERE ( attr_value_id
>       IN ( 655, 656, 658 ) 
>       AND attr_value_id
>       IN ( 589 ) )
>       GROUP BY product_id
>       HAVING COUNT( product_id ) >1

But this wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Because the EAV model "spreads" the attributes of what would be a single record (under traditional relational model) into multiple table row, one needs to use self joins like the following to search items on the basis of multiple attributes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.product_id    -- see note about DISTINCT, below
FROM ka_product_attribute A1
JOIN Ka_product_attribute A2 ON A1.product_id == A2.product_id
WHERE A1.attr_value_id = 589
  AND A2.attr_value_id in (655, 656, 658)

-- The 'DISTINCT' is only necessary if duplicates are allowed for values of the
-- attribute 589. (in other words if ka_product_attributes can have several
-- records with for a product_id + attr_value_id combination).
```

Comment: Join, of course! Thank You! I'll try it tomorrow, because I have to build the query dynamically from an array, and I'm too tired now.